# Why doesn't delegate call the function?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

1: Can someone explain the last line of the first function to me?

2: The second function doesn't work. Please tell me why.The PHP script is fetching the data.

I edited the code to get this, but the app now crashes with a System nullreferenceexception.
Please help.

```
    private void checkbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        statustext.Text = "Checking for new score";
        var webclient = new WebClient();
        webclient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(getscores_OpenReadCompleted);
        webclient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/get.php?"+DateTime.Now));


    }
    void getscores_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader s = null;
        Stream reply=null;
        try
        {

               reply = (Stream)e.Result;
                 s = new StreamReader(reply);                  

            }

        catch 
        {
            statustext.Text = "ERROR IN FETCHING";
        }
        scorebox.Text = s.ReadToEnd();
        statustext.Text = "DoNE";

    }
```

Comment: this is one of those areas where you can make some use of a [Debugger](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging) to check and see if statustext.Text is actually getting set, or if there's some sort of other binding issue

Comment: You should try moving the delegate registration above the call to `OpenReadAsync`

Comment: In addition to what xDaevax said (because otherwise OpenReadCompleted  may be fired before you register your handler) you should also dispatch getscores_OpenReadCompleted into UI thread. Setting Text property from another thread isn't allowed.

Comment: the exact code in the tutorial seemed to work well, but this doesn't display anything at all. In fact, I don't think the second function even gets executed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. Register the delegate before the call to `OpenReadAsync`
2. Read the stream from the event arguments and close the stream when you're done.

---

```
private void checkbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    statustext.Text = "Checking for new score";
    var webclient = new WebClient();
    webclient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(getscores_OpenReadCompleted);
    webclient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/get.php?"+DateTime.Now));

}
void getscores_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Stream reply = null;
    StreamReader s = null;
    string outputText = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        reply = (Stream)e.Result;
        s = new StreamReader(reply);
        outputText = s.ReadToEnd();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (s != null)
        {
            s.Close();
        }

        if (reply != null)
        {
            reply.Close();
        }
    }
    statustext.Text = outputText;

}
```

See the usage of the `OpenReadAsync` method here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.openreadcompletedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx
  and here
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144211(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi! can you help me with a simple app to rad data from a SQL database, and display it.

Answer (score 6):

The last line of the first method is attaching a handler to an event.  It is saying that when the `OpenReadCompleted` event fires, that is to say when the read completes, the `getscores_OpenReadCompleted` method should be called.

The `getscores_OpenReadCompleted` doesn't work because it's trying to access a UI element from a non-UI thread.

You're also adding the handler after starting the asynchronous operation, so while it's unlikely, it's certainly possible that the operation completes *very* quickly and the event is fired before you add the handler.  While this situation would be *very* unusual, it's fixed very quickly and easily by simply adding the handler before you start the asynchronous operation.